# PRE-LOGIN FLOW!... error happens in instabot

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to use instabot https://github.com/instagrambot/instabot ,but - INFO - 'ds_user_id' error happens.

First,I set default parameters.Second,I run `python like_hashtags.py follow` and I put 1 which is my account,so INFO - PRE-LOGIN FLOW!... error happens.
Traceback is

```
KeyError: 'ds_user_id'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "like_hashtags.py", line 35, in <module>
    sleep(retry)
NameError: name 'sleep' is not defined
```

I deleted secret.txt but same error happens.How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line with:

```
sleep(retry)
```

To:

```
import time
time.sleep(retry)
```

Comment: thank you,the error is deleted,but `2020-01-22 18:49:08,733 - INFO - 'ds_user_id' `error happens.How should I do it?

Comment: @Rose2017 That's already going to a different question, you should ask another question, and remember to accept and upvote too :P

Comment: I posted 
new question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59858749/info-ds-user-id-error-happen-in-instabot  .If you know something,please help me.