# INFO - 'ds_user_id' error happen in instabot

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to use instabot https://github.com/instagrambot/instabot ,but INFO - 'ds_user_id' error happen.
First,I set default parameters.Second,I run `python multi_script_CLI.py` and I selected 1->2->1 and put hashtags,the error happens.

I deleted secret.txt but same error happens.How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instabot creates a config folder in whatever directory your program is running in, try deleting that folder and rerunning your program